# Mypy returns Error "Unexpected keyword argument" for subclass of a decorated class with attrs package

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing, python-attrs

I have two decorated classes using [attrs package](https://pypi.org/project/attrs/) as follows:

```py
@attr.s(kw_only=True)
class Entity:
    """
    base class of all entities
    """
    entity_id = attr.ib(type=str)
    # ...

@attr.s(kw_only=True)
class Customer(Entity):
    customer_name = attr.ib(type=Name)
    # ...
```

I get `Unexpected keyword argument "entity_id" for "Customer"` for code like this:

```py
def register_customer(customer_name: str):
    return Customer(
        entity_id=unique_id_generator(),
        customer_name=Name(full_name=customer_name),
    )
```

So how can I make **Mypy** aware of the `__init__` method of my parent class. I should mention that the code works perfectly and there is (at least it seems) no runtime error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is correct and should work. If I run the following simplified version:

```py
import attr

@attr.s(kw_only=True)
class Entity:
    """
    base class of all entities
    """
    entity_id = attr.ib(type=str)
    # ...

@attr.s(kw_only=True)
class Customer(Entity):
    customer_name = attr.ib(type=str)

def register_customer(customer_name: str) -> Customer:
    return Customer(
        entity_id="abc",
        customer_name=customer_name,
    )   # ...
```

through Mypy 0.910 with attrs 21.2.0 on Python 3.9.7 I get:

```
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

---

My theories:

- Old Mypy (there's a lot of changes all times, sometimes it takes time for the attrs plugin to be updated with new features).
- Old attrs (we try to keep up with the changes in attrs and the features provided by Mypy).
- Python 2 (since you're using the old syntax). `kw_only` used to be Python 3-only and I wouldn't be surprised if mypy has some resident logic around it?

Comment: my Mypy and attrs versions are the exact same. but I'm using Python 3.8.5. Thank you now I know there's nothing wrong with the code but tooling.